# Como puedo mostrar un AlertDialog dentro de una Barra de Progreso

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alertdialog, progressbar

> No se como puedo mostrar un *AlertDialog*, cuando la barra de progreso
>   vaya por ejemplo al 22%.

Me gustaría que cuando llegue al 22% la barra de progreso, se pare y muestre una ventana AlertDialog, que muestre algo de texto y los botones por defecto, por ejemplo Aceptar y Cancelar. Que cuando pulses a Aceptar el progreso de la barra se reanude y siga con la carga de progreso. Y así completarlo hasta que llegue al 100% de la barra de progreso.

El problema lo tengo que no se como parar la barra de progreso, por ejemplo al 22% y muestre el AlertDialog. Por eso, esta es mi duda. De como seria la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Esto es lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora, y gracias de antemano compañeros;)

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressBar progressBar4;
private int progressStatus4 = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();


    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                carga();
            }
        });
    }

    private void carga(){
        final Dialog dialogCorrect = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogCorrect.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (dialogCorrect.getWindow() != null) {
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            dialogCorrect.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        }
        dialogCorrect.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialogCorrect.setCancelable(false);
        dialogCorrect.show();

        final TextView tv44 = dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.tv44);
        progressBar4 = dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.pb44);
        final TextView txt = dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText("Connect");

        if (progressStatus4 == 100) {
            progressStatus4 = 0; //Reset Values
        }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus4 < 100) {

                    progressStatus4 += 1;

                    try {
                         Thread.sleep(200);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                if(progressBar4.getProgress() >= 20 && progressBar4.getProgress() <= 41){
                                    txt.setText("Update"); 

                                }else if(progressBar4.getProgress() >= 41 && progressBar4.getProgress() <= 71){
                                    txt.setText("GET");

                                }else if(progressBar4.getProgress() >= 71 && progressBar4.getProgress() <= 99){
                                    txt.setText("WHAIT");

                                }else if(progressBar4.getProgress() >= 99 && progressBar4.getProgress() <= 100){
                                    dialogCorrect.dismiss(); //Close PopUp


                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    // Update the progress bar
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar4.setProgress(progressStatus4);
                            progressBar4.setSecondaryProgress(progressStatus4 + 15);
                            // Show the progress on TextView
                            tv44.setText(progressStatus4 + "%");
                        }
                    });


                }
            }
        }).start(); // Start the operation
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo común es mostrar un progressbar dentro de un AlertDialog no viceversa.

Comment: Estoy haciendo unas pruebas y testeando. Lo que mencionas es que se muestre el Alert y luego lance el progressbar. Pero el caso es paralo a mitad para consultar.

Comment: Te recomiendo tomarlo como 2 cosas por separado, podrías tener un onProgressChanged listener que vaya controlando el progreso de la barra, cuando llegue al porcentage x que querés, paras la ejecución de lo que te está actualizando tu progressbar y abrís y le das show al dialog, y en alguno de los onClick del dialog llamas a la función (quizas un lambda o callback) que reanude la ejecución del actualizador de progreso que tengas. Por último no utilices un handler con un runnable para actualizar un progress, para eso están los listeners, son hilos ejecutandose asincronicamente